# Free shipping IF there is ANY product with a specific shipping class in the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My customer has all their products with a standard shipping cost. They also have a single product (a mystery box) which has a free shipping class assigned to it.

Requirement: If the mystery box product is in the cart, all shipping for all products should be free. In essence, the offer is “If you buy the mystery box, all shipping is free, no matter what else you have in your cart.”

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Using flat rate shipping you can setup per class the price https://woocommerce.com/document/flat-rate-shipping/

Comment: If you need to alter your shipping by checking whats in the cart use woocommerce_package_rates. There are many examples here and on google how to use it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?